# Finding the eigenvector given eigenvalue and $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am studying for an exam for work which is covering some linear algebra which I am having some difficulty with.

I have the following $(2 \times 2)$-matrix:
$$
    A
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      3 & 1 \\
      2 & 4
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
And I have the eigenvalue $5$.

How would I go about solving for the eigenvector? I know the following formula:
$$
  A(\text{eigenvalue}) = (\text{eigenvalue})(\text{eigenvector})
$$

I was thinking that since I have the $A$ and the eigenvalue, I can divide the product of that by the eigenvalue (divide each value in the matrix by $1/5$)?

Any help would be great!

Comment: The eigenvector is the vector $v$ which solves $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, since you know $\lambda=5$, you can solve this as any other matrix-vector problem.

Comment: "*I know that the following formula: A(eigenvalue) = (eigenvalue)(eigenvector)*"   You have this incorrect unfortunately, but it may just be a typo on your part.  Supposing that $\lambda$ is an eigen*value* and $v$ is the corresponding eigen*vector*, you would have $Av=\lambda v$.  You wrote $A\lambda = \lambda v$ which doesn't make sense (*on the left you would still have a matrix which was scaled by a scalar while on the right you would have just a vector which is scaled by a scalar, giving a type mismatch error*).

Comment: @User123456789 Since I have 0 on the other side and the eigenvector is multiplied with all this, how would I solve for v?

Comment: To reiterate what was said before, we know that $Av=\lambda v$ for $v$ an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.  We are tasked with finding what vector(s) correspond to eigenvalue $5$ here, so we are trying to solve $Av=5v$.  After rearranging this, we're trying to find the vectors $v$ which satisfy $(A-5I)v=0$, that is to say we are trying to find the kernel or nullspace of the matrix $(A-5I)$, something which you should have been taught how to do week one of a linear algebra course.

Comment: @JMoravitz Wow I totally messed that formula up thank you for that catch! With that being said, I can simply just plug in values into the formula and solve for v right?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for that response. I took this linear algebra course 7 years ago and I have not really worked with any of this since then. I am applying for a job that has a standardized exam and this is one of the topics covered. My question is still solving for the v. In the example below that José wrote, I am thrown of as I am consistently getting 0=0 or x=x for the solutions for x and y. I am struggling to understand the steps to get you to the solution (1,2).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3&1\\2&4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then, since you were told (correctly) the $5$ is an eigenvalue, your approach is fine: solve the system $A\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right)=5\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, that is, the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3x+y=5x\\2x+4y=5y,\end{array}\right.$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-2x+y=0\\2x-y=0.\end{array}\right.$$Take $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ as a solution, for instance.

Comment: That makes sense so far José thank you. My question is coming to the (1, 2) as the solution. Would I set the top and the bottom equations equal to each other and solve via substitution etc for x and y?

Comment: @rmahesh You solve it any way you want (as long as the method is a valid one). What I did was to notice that the too equations are equivalent. Then I forgot the second one and I chose a solution of the first one.

Comment: @rmahesh "*Would I set the top and bottom equations equal to eachother.*"  No.  "*Would I ... solve via substitution?*" You are certainly allowed to, especially for small problems like this.  A more general approach would be to use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) (*i.e. "row reduction"*).

Comment: I am getting 0 = 0 so how would I go about getting the values (1,2) even if i were to use Guassian elimination? I am very new to this so please bear with me if I am asking very simple questions.

Comment: @rmahesh Using Gaussion elimination, you get a system that consts of two equation: $x-\frac12y=0$ and $0=$. The second one is irrelevant here. Find a solution of the first one.

Comment: Please let me know if I am on the right track. When I solve for x and y using the very first equation, I am getting y = 2x, x = 1/2y. When I plug in y, I am getting x=x. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @rmahesh once you are at $x-\frac{1}{2}y=0$ (*and a redundant $0=0$*), you can set one of $x$ or $y$ to be a "free variable."  Let's set $y$ equal to the free variable $t$.  We can write $x$ and $y$ now in terms of only free variables: $x=\frac{1}{2}t$ and $y=t$.  That is, $\binom{x}{y}=\binom{t/2}{t}$, or factoring out the $t$ we have $\binom{x}{y}=t\binom{1/2}{1}$

Comment: I think I understand what you are gearing at. But what good would replacing y with t be? The issues I am still facing the same issue that even when focusing only on the first equation, I would get (x-1/2t=0). t, which is essentially y, would be 2x. I feel that that is putting me in the similar situation as before. Can you possibly expand upon your last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, given a matrix $M$ and an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$, there is not only one associated eigenvector. The set of all eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$ is a linear subspace (of $\mathbb{R}^2$ here).

$X=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ $\Leftrightarrow M\cdot X = \lambda X$
$$\Leftrightarrow(M-I_2\lambda)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=0_{\mathbb{R}^2}$$
Which is a system of equations whose set of solutions is indeed a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So in your cases, you have :
$$\Leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=0_{\mathbb{R}^2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow -2x+y=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2x=y$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ 2x\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

So if we call $E_5(M)$ the linear space of all eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue 5, you know that $E_5(M)\subset \text{span}\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right)$.

$E_5(M)$ being a linear subspace of a linear space whose dimension is 1, it is either the null space, or equal to span$\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right)$

And since $\text{dim}(E_5(M))\geq1$ (because 5 is indeed an eigenvalue of M), then $E_5(M)= \text{span}\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right)$.